# Chart column in asp.net repeater/list view / data grid?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.Net.

How can I add a chart column in an asp.net repeater/list view / data grid (whatever possible)?

I want to feed the chart with data from a dataSet.

Please can somebody through light on this?

Comment: what type of chart are you working with? Can you post some of your HTML/ ASP.Net code?

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to get a chart in a Repeater/ListView, I'd suggest first ensuring that you can have a single chart display on a page.

Have you already selected a charting library? Microsoft's Chart Controls are a free option if you are using ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 or beyond. They have a bit of a learning curve, but can be used to plot the data from a DataSet.

I'd suggest you start by familiarizing yourself with the Microsoft Chart Controls and once you are comfortable with them I think you'll find them easy enough to add to a ListView/Repeater... if not, you can come back and update your question specifying the problems you're having.

For further information check out: [Using Microsoft's Chart Controls in an ASP.NET Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx).

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.